# Operator+= on vector failed

Tags: c++, operators, runtime-error

```
template <class ElementType,int Dimension=1>  
class Vector : public vector<ElementType> {  
    public:

    Vector & operator+= (const Vector & a){  
        cout << " a " << a << endl;  
        transform (this->begin(), this->end(), a.begin(), this->begin(), plus<ElementType>());  
        return *this;  
    };  

  friend ostream & operator<< (ostream & stream, Vector t) {
      stream << "(";
      copy (t.begin(), t.end()-1, ostream_iterator<ElementType>(stream,","));
      return stream << *(t.end()-1) << ")";
  };

};
```

1) During runtime I get the error message:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'  
what():  std::bad_alloc
```

I've found that this message is caused by `cout << " a " << a << endl;`

2) Without that `cout << .....` operation finished successfully but some garbage is added to `this` instead of contents of a.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you use `t.end()-1`? If the vector is empty that value won't even exist.

Comment: Have you tried running in a debugger? You should be able to see the line that causes this by checking the backtrace.

Comment: Why your operator << not apply const reference for vector, but vector object?

Comment: Also note: `std::vector` does not have a `virtual` destructor and should not be used as a base class.

Comment: There is no check that the rhs vector is large enough.

Answer (score 2):

There exists std::valarray for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

This output operator

```
friend ostream & operator<< (ostream & stream, Vector t)
```

can possibly cause a `bad_alloc` because it copies the Vector parameter.

You can try this instead

```
friend ostream & operator<< (ostream & stream, const Vector& t)
```

to avoid that.

To avoid the problem with an empty vector not having an `end()-1` you might want to put the output inside an `if (!t.empty())`.

And finally this expression `*(t.end()-1)` can be simplified to `t.back()`.

Comment: Thanks Bo, this eliminates `bad_alloc`.
Not clear why, but works.
Cant it be the same reason for garbage appearing instead of values of vector a?

Comment: The reason for a `bad_alloc` would be that you run out of memory when creating extra copies. The `+=` operator assumes that the two vectors have the same size. If `a` has a different size than thevector added to, it will not work at all.